# ValueNotifier is not returning that data which is being initialized Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `ValueListenableBuilder` to update my UI based on the data provided to it. I am initializing the `ValueNotifier` with value. But when I tried to read that value it returns nothing.

This is my Notifier class code:

```html
class AppValueNotifier
{
  ValueNotifier<List<Food>> valueNotifier = ValueNotifier([]);

  void updateDealsList(List<Food> list)
  {
    valueNotifier.value=list;
    print('DEAL LIST IN CLASS: ${ valueNotifier.value}');
  }
  List<Food> getDealList()
  {
    return valueNotifier.value;
  }
}
```

In a separate widget I am initializing the value like this:

```html
class HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  AppValueNotifier appValueNotifier = AppValueNotifier();

.
.
.

assignList(List<Food> dealList)
{
          appValueNotifier.updateDealsList(dealList);
}
..
..
.
}
```

Now in another widget class I am building my UI with this data like this:

```html
AppValueNotifier appValueNotifier = AppValueNotifier();

Widget buildList()
{

return ValueListenableBuilder(
                            valueListenable: appValueNotifier.valueNotifier,
                            builder: (context, List<Food> value, widget) {
                              print(
                                  'DEAL LIST: ${appValueNotifier.getDealList()}');
                              return DealsWidget(
                                key: menuItemsKey,
                                updateList: (oldIndex, newIndex, newList) {},
                                currentMenu: value,
                                menuItemNodes: [],
                                changeCellColor: (color, catid) {},
                              );
                            },
                          );
 }
```

But it is returning empty list instead. Not that list which is being initialized at the start.

Anyone help me what is the issue here:

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you call `appValueNotifier.updateDealsList(dealList);`? Can you share your full page code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to initialize your ValueNotifier list either in the constructor or based on an action (i.e. a button click, as shown below). Notice how I'm providing the AppValueNotifier service using the Provider pattern, and one widget triggers the action while a separate widget listens to the changes being made.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(
    Provider(
      create: (context) => AppValueNotifier(),
      child: MyApp()
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TriggerWidget(),
            Expanded(
              child: MyWidget(),
            )
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Food {
  final String name;
  Food({ required this.name });
}

class AppValueNotifier
{
  ValueNotifier<List<Food>> valueNotifier = ValueNotifier([]);

  void updateDealsList(List<Food> list)
  {
    valueNotifier.value = list;
    print('DEAL LIST IN CLASS: ${ valueNotifier.value}');
  }
  
  List<Food> getDealList()
  {
    return valueNotifier.value;
  }
}

class TriggerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    AppValueNotifier appValueNotifier = Provider.of<AppValueNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    
    return TextButton(
      child: const Text('Add Items!'),
      onPressed: () {
        appValueNotifier.updateDealsList([
            Food(name: 'Food 1'),
            Food(name: 'Food 2'),
          ]);
      },
    );
  }
        
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    AppValueNotifier appValueNotifier = Provider.of<AppValueNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: appValueNotifier.valueNotifier,
        builder: (context, List<Food> value, widget) {

          var list = value;

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(list[index].name);
            }
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You get this as output:

[image]

Also checkout this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/bbe1cee7d5c69cc0fce3b1af6bc8ba0c) you can run on DartPad.dev to check out how it works.

Comment: My structure of code is different from your provided example. Could you please guide me this solution specifically for my case. I have updated my post with some additional code.

Comment: You are initializing ```valueNotifier``` and using ```ValueListenableBuilder``` in the same widget class. But my case is different. I am initializing the value earlier in a widget class and using that value in a child class which is deep down in a widget tree.

Comment: Oh I see. You should then provide the service from up above the hierarchy (i.e. using a Provider widget) and should work as well. I can modify the example if you want.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated answer above, as well as this Gist (https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/bbe1cee7d5c69cc0fce3b1af6bc8ba0c) to check out the approach proposed. Thanks